# Go database/sql Changing Case of Table Name

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to query a database using `database/sql` and the `github.com/lib/pq` Postgres driver. The error I'm encountering is:

```
pq: relation "itemprices_itemsale" does not exist
```

However looking at my query:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM \"itemPrices_itemsale\" LIMIT 10")
```

You'll notice the capital 'P' in the table name. I've learned form poking around that Postgres will fold names in to lowercase if they are not quoted. I have quoted my table name so I'm not quite sure why this is happening. I'm fairly certain this is the issue as I'm able to query the table using that table name from a similar Python program and everything is working as expected.

Update:
Using @JohnWeldon's suggestion:

```
var table = "itemPrices_itemsale"
rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 10", pq.QuoteIdentifier(table)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `QuoteIdentifier` function in `github.com/lib/pq` to quote your table name:

https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#QuoteIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works and may avoid SQL injections when receiving the table name from an untrusted source, but is a bit verbose for a simple query.

You can just use backsticks and quote the table name manually:

```golang
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM "itemPrices_itemsale" LIMIT 10`)
```